# How to fit inner div inside an outer div

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 300px; position: absolute; right: 25%; top: 5%; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 40px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); -moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 40px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow: 2px 4px 40px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);">
    <section class="notif notif-warn">
        <h6 class="notif-title">Warning!</h6>
        <p>This task was forced checked out by another user. Your changes will not be saved Site.Master.</p>
        <div class="notif-controls">
            <a href="#" class="notif-close" id="cBtn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sikni8/kb2r6d4c/1/

How can I update my CSS to ensure the inner DIV fits within the outer DIV with box shadow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.notif` class or remove the 100% width.

The problem is that when you add 100% width + padding to an element it will cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the width from `.notif`:

```
.notif {
    width: 100%;
}
```